# Sed or awk Find a string in the last 100 characters of a line or delete the line

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

first question so hopefully I form it well.

I'm looking to match a string, namely "lang":"en" in the last 100 characters of a line and if there's no match, delete the line.

I have tried using sed by doing

```
sed '/"lang":"en"/!d' file > output
```

But unfortunately many lines have that string more than once and I only care about the final occurrence of it.

I'm learning sed still, but don't know anything about awk and most of my searches have come up with "first/last instance in a file" rather than "in a line" so any help in learning the best method to do this would be great.  thanks.

Comment: what about piping `tail -c 200` to sed?

Comment: @Emil Kakkau, how exactly will piping the last 200 bytes of a file to `sed` be of any help?  Hedekar is looking for `"lang":"en"` in the last 100 characters of a line... _and also said_ ... "But unfortunately many lines have that string more than once and I only care about the final occurrence of it.".  So I fail to see how this is helpful, as is!

Comment: @user3439894 look at his question: "find a string in the last 100 characters". so piping further will let him find sth in the last 100 characters. in complete sth like `tail -c 200 file.search | grep "lang"; echo $?` will indicate that there is sth. therefore question answered but in fact i am not sure if that fits his need its just a comment, also due to not noted completely.

Comment: @Emil Kakkau, You need to reread the OP "...in the last 100 characters of a line..." and what you propose has the potential to output more then one line.

Comment: @user3439894 wah thanks man. overread this .. *line* just shuffles magically to *file* for me. it is late :)

Answer (score 4):

This should work with any Posix awk:

```
awk 'match(substr($0,length-99),/"lang":"en"/)' file
```

You can do it with a simple string find, instead of a regular expression, but the string is more annoying to type:

```
awk 'index(substr($0,length-99),"\"lang\":\"en\"")' file
```

Both simply extract the last 100 characters of each line, and if the test pattern is found in the substring, print the line (print is the default action, so the program consists only of the condition.)

Answer (score 1):

For a simple regex-based solution,

```
grep -E '"lang":"en".{0,89}$' file
```

I subtracted the length of `"lang":"en"` from the maximum amount, assuming you mean the string must be found entirely within the last 100 characters.

This looks like you are attempting to process JSON data, so perhaps you can come up with a better, structure-based rule, and use `jq` instead.

```
jq 'select(path["to"]["lang"] == "en")' file
```

to find `"en"` in the structure `"path": { ... "to": { ..., "lang": "en" ...} } }`.  This will also be robust against newlines in the JSON, spacing variations in `"lang":   "en"`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/"lang":"en".\{0,89\}$/!d' file > output
```

Add the possible 89 other char before the end in the selection

Comment: Points for showing me the sed formatting that I just wasn't getting.  Thanks.